# Can someone break this complex map function down for me?

Tags: javascript

Found this answer to a question on codefights. I've spent 30 minutes now trying to break it down but I'm not getting anywhere. Really want to figure this out. Can anyone break it down for me, please?

```js
const test1 = [
  ['7', '.', '.', '.', '4', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
  ['.', '.', '.', '8', '6', '5', '.', '.', '.'],
  ['.', '1', '.', '2', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
  ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '9', '.', '.', '.'],
  ['.', '.', '.', '.', '5', '.', '7', '.', '.'],
  ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
  ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '2', '.', '.'],
  ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
  ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
];

//Turn columns into rows
var transpose = grid =>
    grid[0].map(
        (_,c) => grid.map(
            row => row[c]
        )
    );
    
var r = transpose(test1);
console.log(r);
```

Comment: It does what it is named after. It takes transpose of an matrix meaning changing each and every row of a given matrix to column of output matrix.

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code and reviewing the API for each method? There's nothing particularly complicated there.

Comment: It iterates over the first row and replaces it with a column.

Comment: (_,c) what does this mean?

Comment: @divine ask another question. Or have a look at arrow funcs

Comment: @divine underscore is generally used when you don't care what the parameter is. For instance if you have an event handler where the event object itself is unimportant: `.addEventListener('click', _ => ...)`

Comment: Thanks, I know what arrow functions are and how to use them. I know 'what' it does. I'm asking how it does it. sheesh almost sorry I asked.

Comment: @shawn rieger that wasnt addressed to you

Comment: @Jonasw oh missed that. my bad.

Comment: @shawn rieger no worries ;) it annoys me too when people spam the comment area with unnecessary stuff... :/

Answer (score 1):

The output needs to have as many rows as there are columns in the input, so the first map iterates over the number of columns in the input.  The second map iterates over the rows of the input to extract each column and return it as a row for the output.

Comment: Because the output needs to have a row for each column.  By iterating the first row, you are iterating over the number of columns, so the second map ignores the value in the array (that's the underscore variable) and instead is just using the index (that's the `c` variable).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe two regular for loops make it more clear:

```
function transpose(arr){
 var transposed=[];
 for(var row=0;row<arr[0].length;row++){
   var inner=[];/*new row*/
   for(var column=0;column<arr.length;column++){
    inner[column /*now row*/]=arr[column][row];
   }
  transposed.push(inner);
 }
return transposed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grid[0].map((_, c) => ...)
```

Parse each items of the first row of the grid (`['7', '.', '.', '.', '4', '.', '.', '.', '.']`) and pass the index of each item to `c`.

```
grid.map(row => row[c])
```

Return, for each row of the grid, the value of the column `c` in a new array.

So it create an array of arrays of columns items: the new grid.